# accessing translated header in FCE fails

Tags: fluid, typo3-8.x

I have a Typo3 Page with several wrappers and referenced elements on it.

I'm using flux-grid to create the content of the wrappers and then access it like this:

```
<v:variable.set name="contentElements" value="{flux:content.get(area:'content', render:'FALSE')}" />

            <ul class="myClass">
                <f:for each="{contentElements}" as="contentElement" iteration="iteration">

                    <li>
                        <h3 data-number="{iteration.cycle}"><a href="#acc_{v:format.sanitizeString(string: '{contentElement.header}')}" class="toggle">{contentElement.header}</a></h3>
                        <ul class="content" id="acc_{v:format.sanitizeString(string: '{contentElement.header}')}">
                            <li>
                                <v:content.render contentUids="{0:contentElement.uid}" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </f:for>
            </ul>
```

Problem is, I always get the default language for `contentElement.header`  instead of the translated version. The content itself that's been fetched via `v:vcontent.render` is shown in the correct language.

What am I doing wrong?

(Typo3 8.7.9)

Comment: Isn't is possible by putting current language condition, passing from controller?

Comment: I don't have a controller. It's a mere layout-file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get the content first and then render it separately:

```
<f:for each="{contentElements}" as="contentElement" iteration="iteration">
                <v:variable.set name="head" value="{v:content.get(contentUids: '{0: contentElement.uid}', render:'0')}" />

                    <v:variable.set name="theContent" value="{v:content.get(contentUids: '{0: head.0.records}', render:'0')}" />

                    <li>
                        <h3 data-number="{iteration.cycle}"><a href="#acc_{v:format.sanitizeString(string: '{theContent.0.header}')}" class="toggle">{theContent.0.header}</a></h3>
                        <ul class="content" id="acc_{v:format.sanitizeString(string: '{theContent.0.header}')}">
                            <li>
                                <f:format.raw>{theContent.0.bodytext}</f:format.raw>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </f:for>
```

Hope it helps someone...